# My ubuntu 20.04 freeze for more than 30 mins now. But the time is read, mouse working but can't click. Power button not turning off

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

Ubuntu 20.04
My ubuntu 20.04 freezed for more than 30 mins now. But the time is read, mouse working but can't click. Power button not turning off. Thank you

Comment: This question has a better chance of getting good answers over in https://askubuntu.com.